How to install agcc-arm-linux-gnueabi on the Raspberry Pi 2B?
Is it possible to install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi on the Raspberry Pi 2b?
How do I install it? Thank you so much for any help.

Why on earth would you WANT a toolchain on a Pi?

You need the 64-bit version of the OS -- which means you need a rev 1.2 version of the Pi 2, ie., one with a 64-bit processor.
